# How to convert MySQL rows to a column of 5

Tags: mysql, sql, string, pivot, window-functions

I'm new to MySQL. I have a datatable and I'll like to convert it to a row of 5.

From `SELECT File FROM tbl_file`. I have

```
+--------+
| File   |  
+--------+
| B.jpg  | 
+--------+
| X.jpg  | 
+--------+
| H.png  | 
+--------+
| C.png  | 
+--------+
| A.gif  |
+--------+
| G.pdf  | 
+--------+
| Y.docx | 
+--------+
| U.jpeg | 
+--------+
```

Here's what I need when the rows are rotated to 5 columns.

```
+-------+--------+--------+-------+-------+
| A     | B      | C      | D     | E     |
+-------+--------+--------+-------+-------+
| B.jpg | X.jpg  | H.png  | C.png | A.gif |
+-------+--------+--------+-------+-------+
| G.pdf | Y.docx | U.jpeg |       |       |
+-------+--------+--------+-------+-------+
```

When the first row is filled to it's limit which is 5, then the next row continues to be filled.

This is what I've tried:

`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(File) FROM tbl_file GROUP BY id;`
I'm not getting what I intended to get.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just handle the display logic in your application code

Comment: @strawberry I already have lots of loops in my app code. Adding this would make it get slower. Since the DB is faster, I considered run it directly and returning a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit ugly... but possible. You can use window functions - but you need a column that defines the ordering of the rows, I assumed `id`.

```
select
        max(case when rn % 5 = 0 then file end) as filea,
        max(case when rn % 5 = 1 then file end) as fileb,
        max(case when rn % 5 = 2 then file end) as filec,
        max(case when rn % 5 = 3 then file end) as filed,
        max(case when rn % 5 = 4 then file end) as filee
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(order by id) - 1 rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by floor(rn / 5)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8c03e7c5941009787a695ed0269a6735)**:

```
filea | fileb  | filec  | filed | filee
:---- | :----- | :----- | :---- | :----
B.jpg | X.jpg  | H.png  | C.png | A.gif
G.pdf | Y.docx | U.jpeg | null  | null
```